# How can I filter out all the elements from the list either smaller or bigger than one number by Divide and Conquer Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to find out from the list of elements which numbers are smaller and which numbers are bigger compare with one number. Below is the code what I have so far. I am trying to implement those two methods ....

```
public MyDynamicList smallerMyList(MyDynamicList m, int e)
public MyDynamicList biggerEqualMyList(MyDynamicList m, int e)
```

below is all my code what i have done so far any hint how to implement those two method will be highly appreciate..

```
public class DivideAndConquerAlgorithms {

public DivideAndConquerAlgorithms(){}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// smallerMyList --> Filters all elements in MyDynamicList smaller than e
//-------------------------------------------------------------------   
/**
 * The function filters all elements of MyDynamicList being smaller than 'e'  
 * @param m: The MyDynamicList we want to check.
 * @param e: The number 'e' we want to compare each element of MyDynamicList 
 to.
 * @return: The new MyDynamicList containing just the elements being smaller 
 than 'e'  
 */ 
 public MyDynamicList smallerMyList(MyDynamicList m, int e){


    MyDynamicList res = null;

    return res; 

   }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// biggerMyList --> Filters all elements in MyDynamicList bigger than e
//-------------------------------------------------------------------   
/**
 * The function filters all elements of MyDynamicList being bigger than 'e'  
 * @param m: The MyDynamicList we want to check.
 * @param e: The number 'e' we want to compare each element of MyDynamicList 
 to.
 * @return: The new MyDynamicList containing just the elements being bigger 
 or equal than 'e'  
 */ 
public MyDynamicList biggerEqualMyList(MyDynamicList m, int e){

    MyDynamicList res = null;

    return res;
}
}
```

This is my MyDynamicLilst class.......

```
public class MyDynamicList{

//--------------------------------------------------
// Attributes
//--------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @param items: It stores the items of MyDynamicList.
 * @param numItems: It represents the number of items of MyDynamicList.
 * @param maxItems: It represents the maximum number of items a MyDynamicList can contain.  
 */
private MyNode head;
private int numItems;

/**
 * The constructor creates 1 instance (1 object) of the class MyDynamicList<br>
 */     
public MyDynamicList(){
    this.head = null;
    this.numItems = 0;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic Operation --> Get number of integers in MyDynamicList: my_get_length
//-------------------------------------------------------------------   
/**
 * Given a concrete MyDynamicList, it returns its number of items.<br>
 * @return: Number of items of MyDynamicList.
 */ 
public int length(){
    //-----------------------------
    //Output Variable --> InitialValue
    //-----------------------------
    int res = 0;

    //-----------------------------
    //SET OF OPS
    //-----------------------------

    //-----------------------------
    // I. SCENARIO IDENTIFICATION
    //-----------------------------
    int scenario = 0; 

    //Rule 1. The number of elements is included in the attribute numItems
    scenario = 1;

    //-----------------------------
    // II. SCENARIO IMPLEMENTATION 
    //-----------------------------
    switch(scenario){   
    //Rule 1. The number of elements is included in the attribute numItems 
    case 1: 
        res = this.numItems;
        break;
    }           

    //-----------------------------
    //Output Variable --> Return FinalValue
    //----------------------------- 
    return res;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic Operation --> Get integer of MyDynamicList at a concrete index: my_get_element
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Given a concrete MyDynamicList and a concrete index, it returns the item placed at that index (if any).<br>
 * @param index: Index of MyDynamicList we are looking for.  
 * @return: Item placed at the desired index of MyDynamicList (ERROR if there is no item at such position).
 */ 
public int getElement(int index){
    //-----------------------------
    //Output Variable --> InitialValue
    //-----------------------------
    int res = 0;

    //-----------------------------
    //SET OF OPS
    //-----------------------------

    //-----------------------------
    // I. SCENARIO IDENTIFICATION
    //-----------------------------
    int scenario = 0; 

    //Rule 1. Valid index
    if ((index >= 0) && (index < numItems))
        scenario = 1;
    //Rule 2. Invalid index
    else
        scenario = 2;

    //-----------------------------
    // II. SCENARIO IMPLEMENTATION 
    //-----------------------------
    switch(scenario){   
    //Rule 1. Valid index
    case 1: 
        //1. We declare a reference node and a count of the elements we have traversed so far
        MyNode current = this.head;
        int count = 0; 

        //2. We look for the node to be consulted  
        while (count < index){
            //2.1. We make current to point to its next node
            current = current.getNext();

            //2.2. We increase the amount of nodes visited so far.
            count = count + 1;
        }

        //3. We assign the result to the info of the desired node
        res = current.getInfo();

        break;

        //Rule 2. Invalid index 
    case 2: 
        res = 0;
        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot get item, invalid index " + index);
        break;

    }

    //-----------------------------
    //Output Variable --> Return FinalValue
    //-----------------------------     
    return res; 
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic Operation --> Add integer to MyDynamicList at a concrete index: my_add_element 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Given a concrete MyDynamicList, an index and an item, it adds the item at the desired index of MyDynamicList (if capacity allows it).<br>
 * @param index: Index of MyDynamicList we want to add the item at.
 * @param item: Item we want to add to MyDynamicList.    
 */ 
public void addElement(int index, int item){
    //-----------------------------
    //SET OF OPS
    //-----------------------------

    //-----------------------------
    // I. SCENARIO IDENTIFICATION
    //-----------------------------
    int scenario = 0; 

    //Rule 1. Valid index, add at head
    if (index == 0) 
        scenario = 1;
    else{
        //Rule 2. Valid index, add after head
        if ((index > 0) && (index <= this.numItems))
            scenario = 2;
        //Rule 3. Invalid index
        else
            scenario = 3;
    }

    //-----------------------------
    // II. SCENARIO IMPLEMENTATION 
    //-----------------------------
    MyNode newNode = null;
    MyNode currentNode = null;

    switch(scenario){   

    //Rule 1. Valid index, add at head
    case 1: 
        //1. We declare a reference node to head
        currentNode = head;

        //2. We create the node 
        newNode = new MyNode(item, null);

        //3. We make newNode to be the first node of MyList 
        this.head = newNode;

        //4. We make the new node to point at current
        newNode.setNext(currentNode);

        //5. We increase numItems
        this.numItems = this.numItems + 1;

        break;

        //Rule 2. Valid index, add after head
    case 2: 
        //1. We declare a reference node to head, and another one pointing to its previous node. 
        //We also declare a count of the elements we have traversed so far
        currentNode = head;
        MyNode previousNode = null;
        int count = 0;

        //2. We look for the place the node should be inserted  
        while (count < index){
            //2.1. We make previous node to point to the current one. 
            previousNode = currentNode;

            //2.2. We make current to point to its next node
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

            //2.3. We increase the amount of nodes visited so far.
            count = count + 1;
        }

        //3. We create the node 
        newNode = new MyNode(item, null);

        //4. We make previous node to point to newNode
        previousNode.setNext(newNode);

        //5. We make the new node to point at current
        newNode.setNext(currentNode);

        //6. We increase numItems
        this.numItems = this.numItems + 1;

        break;

        //Rule 3. Invalid index 
    case 3: 
        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot add item, invalid index " + index);
        break;

    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic Operation --> Remove index of MyDynamicList: my_remove_element 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------   
/**
 * Given a concrete MyDynamicList and index, it removes the item placed at the desired index of MyDynamicList (if any).
 * @param index: Index of MyDynamicList we want to remove its item from.
 */ 
public void removeElement(int index){
    //-----------------------------
    //SET OF OPS
    //-----------------------------

    //-----------------------------
    // I. SCENARIO IDENTIFICATION
    //-----------------------------
    int scenario = 0; 

    //Rule 1. Invalid index
    if ((index < 0) || (index > this.numItems))  
        scenario = 1;
    else{
        //Rule 2. Valid index, remove first node
        if (index == 0)
            scenario = 2;
        //Rule 3. Valid index, remove after first node
        else
            scenario = 3;
    }

    //-----------------------------
    // II. SCENARIO IMPLEMENTATION 
    //-----------------------------
    switch(scenario){   

    //Rule 1. Invalid index 
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot remove item, invalid index " + index);
        break;

        //Rule 2. Valid index, remove first node
    case 2: 
        //1. Update head 
        head = head.getNext();

        //2. We decrease the number of items
        this.numItems = this.numItems - 1;

        break;

        //Rule 1. Valid index, remove after first node
    case 3: 
        //1. We declare a reference node to head, and another one pointing to its previous node. 
        //We also declare a count of the elements we have traversed so far
        MyNode currentNode = head;
        MyNode previousNode = null;
        int count = 0;

        //2. We look for the place the node should be deleted  
        while (count < index){
            //2.1. We make previous node to point to the current one. 
            previousNode = currentNode;

            //2.2. We make current to point to its next node
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

            //2.3. We increase the amount of nodes visited so far.
            count = count + 1;
        }

        //3. Update previous 
        previousNode.setNext(currentNode.getNext());

        //4. We make current to point to null
        currentNode = null;

        //4. We decrease the number of items
        this.numItems = this.numItems - 1;

        break;  
    }
}
}
```

here is my main class

```
 public class MyMain {

 /**
 * This function is used to test the divide and conquer algorithms.
 */
 public static void test(){
    //1. We create the object to test the exercises
    DivideAndConquerAlgorithms ex = new DivideAndConquerAlgorithms();

    //2. We create extra variables for the tests

    // m1 = []
    MyDynamicList m1 = new MyDynamicList();

    // m2 = [9,3,2]
    MyDynamicList m2 = new MyDynamicList();
    m2.addElement(0, 9);
    m2.addElement(1, 3);
    m2.addElement(2, 2);

    // m3 = [4,8,1,3,6,5,2,6]       
    MyDynamicList m3 = new MyDynamicList();
    m3.addElement(0, 4);
    m3.addElement(1, 8);
    m3.addElement(2, 1);    
    m3.addElement(3, 3);            
    m3.addElement(4, 6);
    m3.addElement(5, 5);
    m3.addElement(6, 2);    
    m3.addElement(7, 6);    

    //3. We create extra variables for the results      
    MyDynamicList resM = null;

    //----------------------------
    //test smallerMyList
    //----------------------------
    System.out.println("\n----------- Test: smallerMyList -------------\n");

    /*resM = ex.smallerMyList(m1, 9);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);

    resM = ex.smallerMyList(m2, 9);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);

    resM = ex.smallerMyList(m3, 6);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);
    */
    //----------------------------
    // test biggerEqualMyList
    //----------------------------  
    System.out.println("\n----------- Test: biggerEqualMyList -------------
    \n");

    /*resM = ex.biggerEqualMyList(m1, 9);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);

    resM = ex.biggerEqualMyList(m2, 9);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);

    resM = ex.biggerEqualMyList(m3, 6);
    ex.recursiveDisplayElements(resM);*/        

}

/**
 * Main Method.
 * @param args: We will run the program parameter free, so do not worry 
 about it.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(); 
}

}
```

and  finally my node class

```
public class MyNode {

private int info;
private MyNode next;

public MyNode(int i, MyNode n){
    this.info = i;
    this.next = n;
}

public int getInfo(){
    return this.info;
}

public MyNode getNext(){
    return this.next;
}

public void setInfo(int i){
    this.info = i;
}    
public void setNext(MyNode n){
    this.next = n;
}
}
```

Comment: Why Divide and Conquer? It seems a linear scan is enough

Comment: @Qmick wel this is how am try to implement but if you have better idea you are more then welcome and I am bit new in the algorithm can not go deep down

Comment: The "divide and conquer" approach would be to split the list into sublists and search the sublists.  But this only makes sense if you can search the sublists in parallel.  (If not, a linear scan is simpler and more efficient.)  Also, I can't for the life of me figure out how your `DynamicList` is supposed to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter out?" Do you mean if, given the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and the number 4, you want your `smallerMyList` to return `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: @Jim exactly this is want I want either to find out smaller or bigger and  if you look at my main where I have to compare with MyDynamicList  m1, m2 and m3  with the given number  passing through method parameter. Another thing my list is organised by index wise. All I want to find out which are the numbers smaller and bigger compare with one number.

Comment: @Stephen I have updated MyDynamicList class with comment hope it will help you to figure it out. Please let me know how can I implement

Comment: Nope.  1) The stuff with "scenarios" makes no sense to me.  2) It also make no sense in trying to do divide and conquer search on a linked list.  There is no reasonable implementation of the "divide" step.